# Can I mix simple past and other verb forms?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

> Stalin eliminated the rebels by rounding them up and sending them to concentration camps, then took over their lands.

Is this correct? I'm not sure if using *rounding* and *sending* will affect the
*took* that I used in the later part of the sentence.

Am I supposed to change *took* to *taking*?

Comment: Using 'taking' might make the grammar easier but would not really make sense: The rebels were as 'eliminated' as they were going to be, in the concentration camps. It would be harsh to label the sentence ungrammatical, but a more significant break before the [deleted-form if 'Stalin' or 'he' is omitted] second main clause (', and then ...' // '; he then ...')  signals the change in direction in the second main clause better, and makes interpretation easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your actual question has nothing to do with its title. This question is not about grammar, it's about history.

Which is correct depends on what you want to say:

- Stalin eliminated (by rounding up and by sending). Then he took over. [This is what the original version of your sentence says.]
- Stalin eliminated (by rounding up, by sending, and by finally taking over). [This is your proposed change.]

So, do you want to present the taking over of rebels' land as the last step in their complete elimination, or do you want to present it as what he did after elimination was completed? Both points of view make perfect sense. You just need to make up your mind which one you want to take.

Answer (score 1):

"rounding" and "sending" are not finite verb forms (they are verbal nouns) so they do not affect the tenses in the sentence. Without them, the structure is

> Stalin eliminated the rebels ..., then took over ...

which is absolutely normal.